# Increasing the space between 2 lines in Corel Draw or Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, corel-draw, laser-cutting

I have a project that I have downloaded from the internet...Problem is the materials they have and I have are different thickness. So I need to change the width between 2 lines (slits for pieces to join together)

Can anybody tell how to achieve this in either corel-draw or inkscape  please and thanks

[image: Wing]

So what I wish to do is adjust the size of the 8 slots thanks

Comment: Hi Atomic, welcome to GDSE! Could you add some screenshots to help us understand what you mean? If I understand you correctly all you need to do is select the points/nodes and move them with your curser—but I may be misunderstanding you.

Comment: Thanks for that CAI shall add a picture to my original post.. Thanks for the welcome as well

Comment: Is the file in a vector format? (I assume it is)

Comment: Thanks for the ongoing help CAI...yes its a vector format.....I spoke to some friends at meet up group and they suggested that I do it again in the correct sized material

Comment: I'm voting this question as off-topic, because simple path edit probably can be found in inkscape or corel-draw documentation, or elsewhere in the web.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is select the nodes of the path and move them accordingly.

The **Editing Paths** section of this [Inkscape Tutorial](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html) details how to edit paths and the keys needed to select multiple nodes, constrain the angle of movement etc. in Inkscape.

[image]

Since this is intended to be laser cut for a specific material you probably need the notches to be a specific width. It *may* be easier to remove the current ones and create your own at the intended width. You can do this in Inkscape using **Boolean operations** which are described in the [same Inskcape tutorial](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html). Just delete the existing areas and create a rectangle at the size you need and use the boolean operations to 'cut' them out of the main shape.

[image]

*The quick examples I've shown above are from Adobe Illustrator since that is what I use, but the concept is the same for any vector editing software. This is basic stuff so If you have any trouble just search for tutorials relating to the specific software you are using.*